# Как извлечь корень из 3d матрицы с помощью cmath?

Tags: python, массивы, оптимизация, numpy

```py
import numpy as np
import cmath

arr = -np.ones(shape=(2,4,4), dtype=float)  # initial numpy array 
# arr1 = np.sqrt(a)  # wrong answer
# arr2 = cmath.sqrt(a)  # TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

arr3 = -np.ones(shape=(2,4,4), dtype=complex)

for i in range(arr.shape[0]):
    for j in range(arr.shape[1]):
        for k in range(arr.shape[2]):
            arr3[i,j,k] = cmath.sqrt(arr[i,j,k])  # works but will be very slow
```

Важно обойтись без циклов и прочих итераторов, чтобы обеспечить максимальную скорость вычислений.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`np.sqrt` вполне работает, только на вход надо подавать `numpy array` типа `complex`

```
print(np.sqrt(-np.ones(shape=(2,4,4), dtype=complex)))
```

Как написано в документации:

> If any element in x is complex, a complex array is returned (and the
> square-roots of negative reals are calculated).